# I have paste some error with paste text in UILabel

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uitableview, cell

I have some problem with my created UILabel in tableViewCell. So i have tableView with Textlabel, detail text and my third created label to cell. So i get info from JSON and paste to this third label so its result:

[image]

But when i try to scroll my table i have some problem with time text:

[image]

So when i added UIColor white color for background to this label i have not this idiot behind number. Help please what i doing wrong?

i add my code tableView

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    if(! cell)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

               cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"song"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"artist"];

    UILabel *mainLabel;

    //frame=CGRectMake(Позиция по X, Позиция по Y, Размеры ширина, Раздел высота)

    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 58, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];

    mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

    mainLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"start"];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1@2x.png"]];



    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [tableTrack setBackgroundView:nil];

    [TrackTableView setBackgroundView:nil];

    tableTrack.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    TrackTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:18.0f];

    cell.textLabel.font = f;

    UIFont *f2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:14.0f];

    cell.detailTextLabel.font = f2;

    UIFont *f3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:14.0f];

    mainLabel.font = f3;


    self.tableTrack.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 74, 1024, 1)];
    separatorView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    separatorView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorView];

    self.TrackTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;





    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please provide datasource delegates methods !

Comment: You want see my code project?

Comment: no just the 
cellForRowatIndexPath  delegate method only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this delegate method.. the problem is you are adding labels to dequeed cell only addsubview in when they are created...try this code..

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {



        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];






         if(! cell)
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


         mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 58, 220.0, 15.0)] autorelease];

            mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

            mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

        UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 74, 1024, 1)];
            separatorView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            separatorView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorView];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"song"];

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"artist"];

            UILabel *mainLabel;

            //frame=CGRectMake(Позиция по X, Позиция по Y, Размеры ширина, Раздел высота)


            mainLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"start"];

            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1@2x.png"]];



            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            [tableTrack setBackgroundView:nil];

            [TrackTableView setBackgroundView:nil];

            tableTrack.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            TrackTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:18.0f];

            cell.textLabel.font = f;

            UIFont *f2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:14.0f];

            cell.detailTextLabel.font = f2;

            UIFont *f3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica 35 Thin" size:14.0f];

            mainLabel.font = f3;


            self.tableTrack.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;



            self.TrackTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;





            return cell;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is you have allocated the label in (else part)outside of the if condition if(cell==nil). You should only create the labels once, when the cell is first created.

When we run the code the control checks whether the cell is nil or have any values. If we allocate the label in else part every time (while scrolling also) you are creating a new label every time. If we allocate it in if condition, the label is only allocated once for each cell and we just update the text value when scrolling.

Comment: How this make in my situation? If it's possible help to me?